# How to declare two types of layout access one method first one (Post) next( Ads) using one method in adapter class

Tags: kotlin, methods, android-recyclerview, overriding, android-arrayadapter

Is there possibility to have  post and ads  methods in two class based view?

I tried to do something like this but of course it doesn't work and error it not working (layout ads) Id

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RM5sn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 55, change HolderProduct to RecyclerView.ViewHolder, and also in your NewpostAdapter class declaration change the ViewHolder type from HolderProduct to RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Then adjust overriden methods accordingly.

Comment: I am try this method but  it not working (layout ads) Id  , in line 67

Comment: @surendharsuren You have to modify your code in many places. Did you sole it? should I post my solution? tell me.

Comment: yes, sir tell me a solution